# filtering Geojson data using select option with leaflet

Tags: laravel, leaflet, geojson

## This is what I could do for the select

What I want to do is to dynamically filter the marker on the select.

```
<script>
  $('#ProvEd').on('change', function() {
      var Prov_id = this.value;
     geolayer = L.geoJson(restaurant500,{
        style:function(feature,latlng){

          return{
            opacity: 1.0,
            color:'white',
            fillOpacity:0.1,
            fillColor:'blue',
          }

        },
       }).addTo(map);

 
  });
e.preventDefault();   
      if (inf != null) map.removeLayer(inf);
      inf = L.geoJSON(restaurant500,{
        filter: function (feature, layer) { 
          return feature.properties.libproedu == Prov_id;
        }
      }).addTo(map);
 </script>
```